# Complex Directional Derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, quasiconformal-maps

I'm working on an expository talk using the text Geometric Group Theory by Drutu & Kapovich. On page 722 they give the formula for the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $e^{i\alpha}$ to be $$\partial_{\alpha}f=\partial f + e^{-2i\alpha} \overline{\partial}f$$ Where $\partial f= \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ and $\overline{\partial}f= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}$. Here is my attempt at deriving this formula:
\begin{align*}
\partial_{\alpha} f&= \cos(\alpha) \partial_x f + \sin(\alpha)\partial_y f \\
&=\cos(\alpha) \left(\partial f + \overline{\partial} f \right)+\sin(\alpha)i\left(\partial f - \overline{\partial} f \right) \\
&= e^{i\alpha} \partial f + e^{-i\alpha}\overline{\partial} f
\end{align*}

If someone could help me find my mistake or explain where the extra factor of $e^{-i\alpha}$ is coming from I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Usually the directional derivative is defined by $D_v f(b) = \lim_{t\to 0,t>0} \frac{f(b+vt)-f(b)}{t}$. It is $\Bbb{R}$-linear in $v$. Here it seems they defined it by $\partial_v f(b)=\lim_{t\to 0,t>0} \frac{f(b+vt)-f(b)}{ vt}$ thus obtaining $\partial_v f(b)=v^{-1} D_vf(b)$ which not $\Bbb{R}$-linear in $v$.

Comment: @reuns The goal of the section this appears in is to show the equivalence of $K$-quasiconformality and having a bounded beltrami differential. Do you know what the motivation would be for considering this version of the directional derivative?

Comment: $D_v f(a) = \frac{ v\partial_zf(a)+\overline{v} \partial_{\overline{z}}f(a)}{2}$ where $\partial_z f(a) = D_{1+i} f(a), \partial_{\overline{z}} f(a) = D_{1-i} f(a)$. 
You need to check that for $|\partial_{\overline{z}} f(a)| < |\partial_z f(a)|$ then $f$ maps small circles around $a$ to (almost) ellipses around $a$ rotating in the same direction, and for $|\partial_{\overline{z}} f(a)| > |\partial_z f(a)|$ it maps small circles to ellipses going in the other direction, thus for $|\partial_{\overline{z}} f(a)|=|\partial_z f(a)|$ you are at the singular case where it maps circles to a segment.